# Knockout custom binding descendant $data works only when the property already exists

Tags: knockout.js

everyone. I was reading Knockout js doc [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html), which relates to controling the descendant bindings. The scenario is that I bind the descendant element with the current binding context using applyBindingsToDescendants, and then I try to access a property in that binding context in the descendant element using $data.property_name, it only works when the property_name is already in the original binding_context, if it's added later, then $data.property_name won't work, but it will work if I remove $data, please take a look at this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amoicity/s8jy7u9j/). Can anyone tell me why it behaves like that?

html

```
<div data-bind="addBindingProperties: {addedProp: 'ADDED PROPERTY'}">
    <div>Existing property accessible via $data: <span data-bind="text:   $data.existingProp"></span></div>
    <div>Added property not accessible via $data: <span data-bind="text: $data.addedProp"></span></div>
    <div>Added property accessible by removing $data: <span data-bind="text: addedProp"></span></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.addBindingProperties = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.extend(bindingContext, valueAccessor());
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
        return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({
    existingProp: 'EXISTING PROPERTY'
});
```

result

```
Existing property accessible via $data: EXISTING PROPERTY
Added property not accessible via $data:
Added property accessible by removing $data: ADDED PROPERTY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$data` in here implies your root viewmodel, so this part is wrong `ko.utils.extend(bindingContext, valueAccessor());` because you are just actually extending it to the current context thus, it is not attached to `$data`.

You can extend it to the root context in order for the property to exist in `$data` like:

```
ko.utils.extend(bindingContext, valueAccessor());
ko.utils.extend(bindingContext.$root, valueAccessor());
```